# Sync between Parse and localDataStore

Tags: ios, cocoa, parse-platform, pfquery

I am having trouble synchronizing my local data with Parse data when using ´enableLocalDataStore´. If I don't use local storage everything is fine, but I would like to minimize calls to Parse server. I understand that if I use ´saveEventually´ for newly created objects these will persist (pinned) locally and be synced with Parse when internet connection is available. This also works fine. My problem is that I don´t know the best method to update the local 'dataStore' with Parse 'dataStore' except to call a method that fetches changes remotely and updates locally. Currently,  use the following:

```
-(void) fetchAllFavorites{
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserStats"];
  [query fromLocalDatastore];

  [[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
      if (task.error) {
      }
      else
      {
           [PFObject pinAll:task.result];  
      }
      return task.result;
  }];
}
```

This approach does not account for changes that may have occurred in Parse 'dataStore'. I could just unpin all local objects and fetch whatever is in Parse by calling a method directly. However, I would think there would be a better approach that seamlessly syncs local changes with changes in the Parse 'dataStore'? Is that not the idea behind allowing the use of 'localDataStore' in the first place ? Currently, I can only see that this works one way: you store data locally and then update the Parse 'dataStore' manually, but you don't really sync between these. At least this is the idea I get from some [of the examples](https://parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore) and I wonder if anyone has a good approach to how to: how to enable 'localDataStore' that is continuously synchronized with Parse 'dataStore'? Any suggestions and examples would be very helpful. I am programming in Cocoa but Java examples would also be great. Thanks, T.

Comment: FYI querying the local data store uses an API request just the same as remotely querying.

Comment: I know but it still only queries locally. I wish it would query locally first and if no results found, search remotely

Comment: Have you not looked into their caching policies this could circumvent even needing local datastore

Comment: Yes, but you are not allowed to change the policy once you enable ´localDataStore´. At least this was my experience when I tried different settings with e.g. kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this was to do a local query, and if nothing is there then query the server. In my settings page I have a function that will "sync" with server, fully refresh the pinned objects basically. This isn't that necessary since any time the user edits, removes, or adds an object, I am calling `saveEventually`, `deleteEventually`, `pinInBackground`, `unpinInBackground`, as appropriate. My startup function looks like this. If local objects aren't found, the server is queried and they are pinned so that next time it will only be local.

```
PFQuery *localQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
[localQuery fromLocalDatastore]; // and any other constraints
[localQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(objects.count > 0) {
        self.objects = objects;
    } else {
        PFQuery *remoteQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
        [remoteQuery findObjectsInBackground:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (objects) {
                self.objects = objects;
                [PFObject pinAllInBackground:objects];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: How does this work for pulling new updates after you already have some initial local data? The example above only really makes sense on a fresh app install, if the user had remote data but nothing stored locally yet. How do you detect new updates that have happened server-side while the client was disconnected? (for example: new chat messages received since the last time the app was launched). The code above would only pull your previous chat messages you had saved locally.

Comment: I have messaging in my app and I update that separately from this "ClassName" object. My example shows how I'm managing an object that is only updated by the owner. In messaging, I would pin those messages as they come in (I use push notifications to either refresh the screen or show a notification). Another option is to just always run a remote query on startup and if it returns, then unpin and pin all objects.If it doesn't (no connection), just use the currently pinned objects.

Answer (score 2):

My approach was to write an utility that checks whether something was updated or deleted in the cloud. Everytime I needed to do an update I called:

```
[[ParseLocalDataStoreManager sharedInstance]updateClasses:classes];
//classes is a NSArray
```

I kept track of which classes were already in the localStore and which were not. If a class was not, then I queried and pinned all of its objects. If it was, I only updated the objects that were modified in the cloud, after the last date I updated. I used Parse's

```
[query whereKey:@"updatedAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:lastUpdated];
```

and kept record of `lastUpdated` in 'NSUserDefaults'.

To delete the objects that were no longer in the cloud, I wrote a small cloud function that returned the objects on the cloud for a certain class. Then I compared them to what I had in localStore, and deleted those that were not in the Cloud.

In my case I updated everytime the user opened the app, since no real-time updates were needed. But if you need real time updates, you can set a timer, and call the function update with the classes you want to update in real time.

I uploaded the utility to github: https://github.com/timpalade/ParseLocalDataStoreManager

Intstructions as well as the cloud code can be found on github. Hope this helps!